# Problems with Homebrew on Yosemite

Tags: terminal, homebrew, freetype, osx-yosemite

I'm a newbie to Homebrew, having some problems. Can anyone help? I've been using step-by-step instructions from the belowmentioned website but I ran into a wall. Here's what brew doctor tells me.

I can't install "winetricks" because "freetype" is disabled.
I can't "link freetype" because

"Linking /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.5... 
Error: Could not symlink include/freetype2/config
/usr/local/include/freetype2 is not writable."

http://www.techboxed.com/news/how-to-get-star-wars-the-old-republic-swtor-working-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks-with-wine/

Here's what it says in Terminal:

Iiljas:~ harrilammi$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.3.16.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftconfig.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftheader.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftmodule.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftoption.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftstdlib.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/freetype.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftbbox.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftbdf.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftbitmap.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftcache.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftchapters.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/fterrdef.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/fterrors.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftgasp.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftglyph.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftgxval.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftgzip.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftimage.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftincrem.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftlcdfil.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftlist.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftlzw.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftmac.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftmm.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftmodapi.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftmoderr.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftotval.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftoutln.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftpfr.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftrender.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftsizes.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftsnames.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftstroke.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftsynth.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftsystem.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/fttrigon.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/fttypes.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftwinfnt.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ftxf86.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/t1tables.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ttnameid.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/tttables.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/tttags.h
    /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/ttunpat.h
    /usr/local/include/ft2build.h

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fontforge.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sigc++-2.0.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

```
freetype
```

Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so
    echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
Iiljas:~ harrilammi$ brew install winetricks
Error: You must `brew link freetype' before winetricks can be installed
Iiljas:~ harrilammi$ brew link freetype
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.5... 
Error: Could not symlink include/freetype2/config
/usr/local/include/freetype2 is not writable.

Comment: I would try `brew remove --force freetype` and `brew remove --force winetricks` and then run `brew doctor` again, and correct the warnings. Then start all over again with `brew install freetype` then `brew install winetricks`

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot :) All up and running now :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
brew remove --force freetype
brew remove --force winetricks
```

and then run

```
brew doctor
```

again, and correct the warnings. Then start all over again with

```
brew install freetype
brew install winetricks
```